# Python requests ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Tags: python, python-requests

So I think this party of my code is the important part.
I get the error with the line sample_req.
Which is weird because I already used the commando requests.get earlier on.

```
sample_url = '{0}/sample?'.format(SERVICES_URL)

    sample_args = {
    'product': product['ProductAndVersion'],
    'layer': product_layer['Layer'],
    'startdate': '03-01-2005',
    'enddate': '09-01-2005',
    'coordinate': '{0},{1}'.format(latitude, longitude),
    'format': 'json'
}

sample_req = requests.get(sample_url, params = sample_args)

samples = sample_req.json()
```

Comment: Can you access  `sample_url`  with a web browser ?

Comment: No! https://lpdaacsvc.cr.usgs.gov/services/appeears-api I refer to this  and it's not found with a webbrowser

Comment: Never mind! I got it, thank you. I changed the dates to receive the data